# How to get class's numeric suffix?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

There's a class:

```
<div id="my-id" class"my-class my-class-level-3"></div>
```

How can I get its numeric `my-class-level` suffix (in this case - `3`)? Order of class attributes can be absolutely random.

Comment: Does the `id` relate to the class? Will the class-name always be prefixed by 'my-class-level'? Will it be a known element from which you want to recover the suffix? Will that suffix always be a numeric character? Will you already have the element(s) selected somehow? What portion, or portions, do you know in advance?

Comment: You're almost certainly misusing classes. You should probably have a `data-level="3"` attribute instead, so you can immediately access the value `3` instead of packing data into the class list.

Comment: @DavidThomas 1) Id doesn't relate in anyway, sorry. 2) Yes, it's know, in the above described example it can be easily retrieved via id or class attributes. 3) Yes, it's always numeric, I thought I stated it clearly 4) Here you can refer to my second answer to you 5) I know the element and I know it has above described class with a numeric suffix

Comment: @meagar I will consider  this approach, thank you.

Comment: @Apsed1976 You would be able to simply do `document.getElementById('my-id').dataset.level` and retrieve the value "3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do It:

```
"use strict";

function getSuffix(element) {
    let match;

    if ( match = element.className.match(/my-class.+my-class-level-(\d+)/) )
        return match[1];

    return null;

}

console.log(getSuffix({className: 'my-class random class names my-class-level-5'}));
```

Or you can just set a custom attribute like `level="9"` and retrieve it using `.getAttribute`. or better using `data-level="9"` and get it using `.dataset.level`.

Hope this helps.